# Regex replace: remove property with condition

Tags: regexp-replace

I would like to use Regex replace for removing a certain property from a JSON array with the condition that only items with

- `"name": "entity_to_catch"` **and** `"direction": 4` are getting fetched.
- The other items e.g. `"name": "some_entity1"` should be untouched.

I tried several Regex patterns - also with Regex lookahead - but nothing is fetching the right data.

This is my pattern so far: `(entity_to_catch)(.*?)("direction": 4,)([^}]*)` with removing group 3 `$1$2$4`

This is my data:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "entity_to_catch",
    "position": {
        "x": -68,
        "y": -98
    },
    "type": "input"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "entity_to_catch",
    "position": {
        "x": -58,
        "y": -98
    },
    "type": "input"
},
{
    "id": 1248,
    "name": "some_entity1",
    "position": {
        "x": 64,
        "y": -41
    },
    "direction": 6
},
{
    "id": 1249,
    "name": "some_entity1",
    "position": {
        "x": 67,
        "y": -41
    }
},
{
    "id": 1250,
    "name": "entity_to_catch",
    "position": {
        "x": 67,
        "y": -43
    },
    "direction": 2,
    "type": "input"
},
{
    "id": 1251,
    "name": "some_entity1",
    "position": {
        "x": 70,
        "y": -41
    },
    "direction": 2
},
{
    "id": 1255,
    "name": "entity_to_catch",
    "position": {
        "x": 77,
        "y": -43
    },
    "type": "output"
},
{
    "id": 1256,
    "name": "some_entity1",
    "position": {
        "x": 80,
        "y": -41
    },
    "direction": 2
},
{
    "id": 1364,
    "name": "some_entity1",
    "position": {
        "x": 65,
        "y": -38
    },
    "direction": 2
},
{
    "id": 1365,
    "name": "entity_to_catch",
    "position": {
        "x": 67,
        "y": -38
    },
    "direction": 4,
    "type": "output"
},
{
    "id": 1366,
    "name": "some_entity1",
    "position": {
        "x": 69,
        "y": -38
    },
    "direction": 6
},
{
    "id": 1369,
    "name": "some_entity1",
    "position": {
        "x": 75,
        "y": -38
    },
    "direction": 2
},
{
    "id": 1370,
    "name": "entity_to_catch",
    "position": {
        "x": 77,
        "y": -38
    },
    "type": "input"
},
{
    "id": 1668,
    "name": "entity_to_catch",
    "position": {
        "x": -48,
        "y": -29
    },
    "type": "input"
},
{
    "id": 1669,
    "name": "entity_to_catch",
    "position": {
        "x": -38,
        "y": -28
    },
    "direction": 4,
    "type": "input"
},
```

Data after replacement should look like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "entity_to_catch",
    "position": {
        "x": -68,
        "y": -98
    },
    "type": "input"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "entity_to_catch",
    "position": {
        "x": -58,
        "y": -98
    },
    "type": "input"
},
{
    "id": 1248,
    "name": "some_entity1",
    "position": {
        "x": 64,
        "y": -41
    },
    "direction": 6
},
{
    "id": 1249,
    "name": "some_entity1",
    "position": {
        "x": 67,
        "y": -41
    }
},
{
    "id": 1250,
    "name": "entity_to_catch",
    "position": {
        "x": 67,
        "y": -43
    },
    "direction": 2,
    "type": "input"
},
{
    "id": 1251,
    "name": "some_entity1",
    "position": {
        "x": 70,
        "y": -41
    },
    "direction": 2
},
{
    "id": 1255,
    "name": "entity_to_catch",
    "position": {
        "x": 77,
        "y": -43
    },
    "type": "output"
},
{
    "id": 1256,
    "name": "some_entity1",
    "position": {
        "x": 80,
        "y": -41
    },
    "direction": 2
},
{
    "id": 1364,
    "name": "some_entity1",
    "position": {
        "x": 65,
        "y": -38
    },
    "direction": 2
},
{
    "id": 1365,
    "name": "entity_to_catch",
    "position": {
        "x": 67,
        "y": -38
    },
    "type": "output"
},
{
    "id": 1366,
    "name": "some_entity1",
    "position": {
        "x": 69,
        "y": -38
    },
    "direction": 6
},
{
    "id": 1369,
    "name": "some_entity1",
    "position": {
        "x": 75,
        "y": -38
    },
    "direction": 2
},
{
    "id": 1370,
    "name": "entity_to_catch",
    "position": {
        "x": 77,
        "y": -38
    },
    "type": "input"
},
{
    "id": 1668,
    "name": "entity_to_catch",
    "position": {
        "x": -48,
        "y": -29
    },
    "type": "input"
},
{
    "id": 1669,
    "name": "entity_to_catch",
    "position": {
        "x": -38,
        "y": -28
    },
    "type": "input"
},
```

Comment: I stopped reading at `from a JSON array` ... you should not in general use regex to parse JSON.

Comment: I do not want to parse an JSON array, I want to manipulate some data in it without writing a program for that problem. It's just overkill for one time usage. Also think a bit further e.g. this would be XML or some other format. Solving that problem will get further understanding and power usage of Regex.

Comment: Fair enough.  Can you also show us what the JSON should look like after the replacement?

Comment: As posted in the original question, all items containing `entity_to_catch` and later `"direction": 4` should have no `direction` attribute anymore.